# Vagtant in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, vagrant

**vagrant up**
==> vagrant: A new version of Vagrant is available: 2.2.14 (installed version: 2.2.9)!
==> vagrant: To upgrade visit:[Vagrant Link](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/bioni64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: ~> 201901314.0.0
Vagrant is currently configured to create VirtualBox synced folders with
the `SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate` option enabled. If the Vagrant
guest is not trusted, you may want to disable this option. For more
information on this option, please refer to the VirtualBox manual:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

This option can be disabled globally with an environment variable:

VAGRANT_DISABLE_VBOXSYMLINKCREATE=1

or on a per folder basis within the Vagrantfile:

> config.vm.synced_folder '/host/path', '/guest/path',
> SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: false
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
> ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
> default: Adapter 1: nat
> ==> default: Forwarding ports...
> default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
> ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
> ==> defThere was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown
> below.
> Command: ["startvm", "2ae67e96-d553-415e-9624-c5381293436e", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enable Virtualization from your BIOS. That should solve the problem.